# Text-overflow: ellipsis alignment issue

Tags: html, truncate, rich-snippets, css

I have the product name and pricing as separate spans insides a link to work properly with Rich Snippets. Some products have larger length names than others so I'm truncating the length so it fits the box I have. Previously this was done on the server but I'd prefer to have it handled with CSS so any changes to the design doesn't involve the backend pages changing.

[image]

The problem is I cannot make the spans line up next to each other. With tinkering the display attribute, the text-overflow property does not work. The problematic code is below:

HTML:

```
<div class="details" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product"> 
<h2>
    <a class="heading" href="/product/acmesw" title="Acme Super Widget">
        <span class="trunc" itemprop="name">Acme Super Widget 3000</span>
        <span itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">- <meta itemprop="currency" content="AUD" /><spanitemprop="price">$199.95</span></span>     
     </a>
 </h2>
```

CSS:

```
.details {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.trunc {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width:60%;
}

h2 span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c7p8w/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to answer because your fiddle doesn't show the problem. You should be able to fix the issue by giving both spans the same `vertical-align` setting. Try giving them both `vertical-align:top;`.

Edit: Ah, I see the issue in IE.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c7p8w/1/